# Firefox strange behaviors when exchange offer

Tags: webrtc

I'm currently trying to adapt my peerConnection code from chrome to firefox, the exchange offer work well but i don't understand why the onaddstream event is called while i don't add any stream to the peerConnections? (Everything was tested only beetween firefox clients)

And is it normal that the icecandidates are directly contained in the offer while under chrome it's the icecandidate event that exchange the icecandidates?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox sends the first candidate with the offer, and that is the normal behaviour for now. The onstreamadded is called on the receiver side, because when you inject the offer in the browser, it starts checking the other client, and it gets the remote stream.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this side effect?

I have one more problem, when i try to negotiate the offers one more time with a real stream peerConnection.createOffer fail and i don't know why.